# Block texture load only in the inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am creating a mod but the texture of a block (the only one) loads only in the inventory and when it gets dropped, hope you can help me, I'm using the 1.8 MDK.

Blockstates:

```
    {
    "variants"": {
        "normal": {"model": "horsenexus:horse_block"},
     }
}
```

Models, block:

```
{
    "parent": "block/cube_all",
    "textures": {
        "down": "horsenexus:blocks/horse_block_down",
        "up": "horsenexus:blocks/horse_block_top",
        "north": "horsenexus:blocks/horse_block_north",
        "east": "horsenexus:blocks/horse_block_east",
        "south": "horsenexus:blocks/horse_block_south",
        "west": "horsenexus:blocks/horse_block_west"
    }

}
```

Models, item:

```
{
    "parent": "horsenexus:block/horse_block",
    "display": {
        "thirdperson": {
            "rotation": [ 10, -45, 170 ],
            "translation": [ 0, 1.5, -2.75 ],
            "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
         }
     }
}
```

And the codes:

```
package com.crazyhoorse961.core.blocks;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;

public class HorseBlock extends Block{

    public HorseBlock(Material materialIn) {
        super(materialIn);
        this.setHardness(5.6F);
        this.setResistance(56.34F);
        this.setStepSound(this.soundTypeSnow);
    }

}
```

And the last one:

```
package com.crazyhoorse961.core.init;

import com.crazyhoorse961.core.Reference;
import com.crazyhoorse961.core.blocks.HorseBlock;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class Horse_Block {
    public static Block horse_block;

    public static void init()
    {

        horse_block = new HorseBlock(Material.clay).setUnlocalizedName("horse_block");
    }

    public static void register()
    {
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(horse_block, horse_block.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    }

    public static void registerRenders()
    {
        registerRender(horse_block);
    }

    public static void registerRender(Block block)
    {

        Item item = Item.getItemFromBlock(block);
        Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(Reference.MOD_ID + ":" + item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5), "inventory"));

        }
    }
```

Thank you for trying to help me, have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following line in your "Models, block" code

```
"parent": "block/cube_all",
```

into:

```
"parent": "block/cube",
```

As far as I'm aware 'cube_all' is only used when you use the same texture for all sides of your block.